# How to bind the Delegate used in the Objective c class in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Hi i am new to binding Objective-C to c#. I used the Objective Sharpie for C# binding. I generated the ApiDefinitions.cs file but more error on generated file.

Error:
Error CS0527: Type `MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewDelegate' in interface list is not an interface (CS0527) (IOSBinding)
This Line Cause the Error

C# code

```
 [BaseType (typeof (UITableView))]  
 public partial interfaceA interfacename : UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    }
```

Objective C

```
 @interface interfaceA:UITableView<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{

}
```

How can i bind the UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate in c#?

Comment: Should probably be "public partial class interfaceA : UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate"

Comment: in ApiDefinitions.cs will contain class declaration?

Comment: can you provide the code to bind with Interface in ApiDefinitions.cs fils

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to actually list the protocols that it implements, the binding will work without them.

Side note: Due to the way that protocols work, you wont be able to effectively claim that a class implements a protocol with the Classic API.  That said, the upcoming Unified API solves this problem, and would allow you to do this.